# Why passing a function object as a template argument causes different behavior depending of it being an lvalue/rvalue?

Tags: c++, memory-management

Sorry if the title feels convoluted. Consider the below code, it's not so long (85 lines) and trivial to understand.

```cpp
#include <stdexcept>
#include <stdio.h>

constexpr void assert_that(bool statement, const char* message) {
    if (!statement) throw std::runtime_error{ message };
}

struct SpeedUpdate {
    double velocity_mps;
};

struct CarDetected {
    double distance_m;
    double velocity_mps;
};

struct BrakeCommand {
    double time_to_collision_s;
};

template <typename T>
struct AutoBrake {
    AutoBrake(const T& publish)
        : collision_threshold_s{ 5 },
        speed_mps{},
        publish{ publish } {}

    void observe(const SpeedUpdate& su) {
        speed_mps = su.velocity_mps;
    }

    void observe(const CarDetected& cd) {
        const auto relative_velocity_mps = speed_mps - cd.velocity_mps;
        const auto time_to_collision_s = cd.distance_m / relative_velocity_mps;
        if (time_to_collision_s > 0 &&
            time_to_collision_s <= collision_threshold_s) {
            publish(BrakeCommand{ time_to_collision_s });
        }
    }

    void set_collision_threshold_s(double x) {
        if (x < 1) throw std::out_of_range{ "Collision less than 1." };
        collision_threshold_s = x;
    }

    double get_collision_threshold_s() const {
        return collision_threshold_s;
    }

    double get_speed_mps() const {
        return speed_mps;
    }
private:
    double collision_threshold_s;
    double speed_mps;
    const T& publish;
};

void alert_when_collision_imminent() {
    int brake_commands_published{};
    // case 1: no segfault
    /*
    auto f = [&brake_commands_published](const BrakeCommand&) { brake_commands_published++; };
    AutoBrake auto_brake{ f };
    */

    // case 2: segfault
    /*
    AutoBrake auto_brake{
        [&brake_commands_published](const BrakeCommand&) {
            brake_commands_published++;
        }
    };
    */

    auto_brake.set_collision_threshold_s(10L);
    auto_brake.observe(SpeedUpdate{ 100L });
    auto_brake.observe(CarDetected{ 100L, 0L });

    assert_that(brake_commands_published == 1, "brake commands published not one");
}

int main() {
    alert_when_collision_imminent();
}
```

On GCC 13.2.1 in Arch Linux, the program fails when case 2 is uncommented: it causes a segfault when the callback function accesses `brake_commands_published`.

This doesn't occur in case 1 where, instead of constructing the function object as a rvalue and passing it directly to `AutoBrake`'s constructor, we construct a function object, create an lvalue and then pass that lvalue to the constructor.

I simply don't understand why.

Obs: The code has been extracted from [Josh Lospinoso's C++ Crash Course](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1593278888).

Comment: Tangential side note: `<stdio.h>` is the C header. The corresponding C++ header is `<cstdio>`.

Comment: Consider compiling with `-fsanitize=address` to get extra details about where the bad memory access is occurring

Comment: *"it's [...] trivial to understand."* -- I disagree. In fact, I would argue that almost any code using templates is **not** trivial to understand. (Also, being long enough to trigger a scrollbar in the code block strongly suggests non-trivial.) *And even for trivial code, writing out in words what the code does would demonstrate that you do in fact understand the code.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`AutoBrake`'s constructor saves a reference to its parameter in a class member.

In the first case, the reference is to the object `f`, which remains in scope, it continues to exist, for the duration of the relevant code.

In the second case, the reference is to a temporary object, that goes out of scope and gets destroyed after the object is constructed. `AutoBrake`'s constructor stores a reference to a temporary object. The temporary object gets destroyed after `AutoBrake` gets constructed, and it now holds a dangling reference.

Subsequent usage of the referenced, but destroyed, object becomes undefined behavior.

Comment: Hi Sam, thanks for your answer. I have some questions: The reference the constructor saves is to the callback function. When I debugged the code, it showed that when the callback function `publish` got called, the error was on the access to `brake_commands_published`, so any instruction that doesn't access this variable works just fine. But shouldn't this variable only get destructed after the function `alert_when_collision_imminent` ends, since it has automatic storage duration?

Comment: The error is due to the reference stored in the lambda. In case of rvalue, the lambda doesn't reside where it use to( reference to lambda is dangling); therefore accessing the reference stored inside is UB. Shadowing is blinde folding you.

Comment: Any access of a destroyed object is undefined behavior. The reference itself is a part of the closure, that gets destroyed. The fact that the referenced object still exists is immaterial. The reference itself is distinct from the referenced object.